# Possible to have custom logs in logcat?

Tags: android, logcat

I'm using logcat for monitoring my android projects in a custom way. I export my data,errors,method info and many other options.
I prefer to not to use Log defaults like Lod.d or Log.e or etc.
Is it possible to have my own custome logs for example Log.myLog with a new color in Logcat?
I prefer my logs do not interfere with android logs. 
I've searched a lot but can't find anything about this purpose: 
http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_debugging_with_logcat
http://logc.at/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend you a good one: https://github.com/oronno/log4android

**Features**

- Log syntax similar with popular log4j framework
- Automatically added TAG with log message
- Derive TAG from the package name
- Can disable logging by simply calling Logger.disableLogging(true) method preferably from the class extends Application.
- Fully Qualified Class name or SimpleClassName will logged as prefix with log message
- Variable Arguments (more than 2) can be passed for printing unlike log4j framework
- Very lightweight, < 5KB library size!

I do use it in my every android application.

Answer (score 1):

some time ago i wrote an eclipse plugin that modifies android.util.Log.* calls so that when
you have in your code:

```
Log.d(TAG, "********** this is line 49 in onCreate method");
android.util.Log.d(TAG, "********** this is line 50 in onCreate method");
```

you will see in the LogCat:

```
D/Test    (  306): onCreate:49, ********** this is line 49 in onCreate method
D/Test    (  306): onCreate:50, ********** this is line 50 in onCreate method
```

the plugin sources are here: https://github.com/pskink/AndroidLoggerBuilder.git

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to establish its own tag for its log? You can then easily filter logs without having to allocate a different color.